# Hash calculation for array of long values in C#

Tags: c#, performance, hashcode, simd

Can the following function be improved in terms of performance?

I am calculating millions of such hashes.
The long array represents a record from data table where all values are encoded as long values. Usually in one calculation stream all arrays are of the same length but in some rare cases this rule does not apply.
Typical length of the array vary from 300 to 1 elements.

I was wondering whether using SIMD (SSE / AVX) instructions in `System.Numerics.Vectors` library of .NET 4.6 could help?

```
public static int GetHashCode(long[] array)
{
    if (array == null) return 0;
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            hash = 31 * hash + array[i].GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a 32-bit process or a 64-bit process?

Comment: Do rows sometimes only differ is small parts? If not, you could simply leave out some of the inputs.

Comment: @CodesInChaos this is 64-bit process. Yes rows often differ only in small parts.

Comment: A common approach is to only hash the first x (like 6-20) rows.

Comment: More important is how is it going to be used?   Hash is only Int 32.   You are using multiple long just to find a bucket.   Right now this imperfect  hash is more expensive than a comparison (equals).   Equal would check length and then element by element compare and stop once it finds an inequality.   In real life I bet you would be better with length and the first 6 values.    With different primes so order matters.   Sorry but to use up to 300 long to create an Int 32 is silly.

Comment: @Paparazzi If I understand you right, hash function should be changed to use only first m array elements to compute hash and should be less expensive than equal function. Each array element that is used to compute hash should be multiplied be different prime number. Is that correct?

Comment: @SebastianWidz Yes.  Again how are you using the the hash?

Comment: What does your data represent? Can you leave out some of the data during hash calculation?

Answer (score 4):

You could use **XOR** to combine hashes which is much faster than your calculation:

```
int hash = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    hash ^= array[i].GetHashCode();
return hash;
```

Comment: Doing nothing but XOR has issues with hash collisions, both because XOR is commutative (e.g., abc hashes to the same value as cba) and because it biases to zero values (a XOR b = 0 for any a = b, which happens frequently in real-world data).  You could toss in a multiplication with a prime number before or after the XOR function to resolve that, though.

Comment: @DanLyons Multiplication is also commutative.

Comment: @Paparazzi: Whether multiplication is commutative is irrelevant; it is not commutative *with xor*.  `(A * B) ^ C` and `A * (B ^ C)` can have completely different values; consider A, B, C all equal to 2, for example.

Comment: @DanLyons: Can you briefly explain why prime numbers have a desirable property as a multiplicand?

Comment: @EricLippert To be honest, I haven't enough math background to say whether a prime is better than other numbers -- that's what I've seen used in many different hashing algorithms (e.g., [FNV-1 and FNV-1a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function))

Comment: @EricLippert With XOR?   Where is the proposal for mixing?  This is code review.  The code to be reviewed  is multiplication so yes I consider it relevant.

Comment: @Paparazzi: The proposal for mixing them is the comment you replied to. It is in the sentence "... toss in a multiplication ... before or after the XOR".

Comment: @DanLyons: Indeed, there is much cargo cult programming in hash methods. Someone heard from someone else that the multiplier has to be a prime, accepted it uncritically, and passed the lore along. FYI, the actual property you want is that *the number chosen be coprime to the number of buckets in the hash bucket list*.  Note that not all prime numbers have this property!  If there are 7 buckets in the bucket list then the prime number 7 is NOT coprime to the size of the bucket list!  Now that we have the real requirement, do you see why the requirement exists?

Comment: @EricLippert good to know :)  How does that change for hash code generation when you don't know how many buckets there will be, such as a `GetHashCode()` override?

Comment: I have checked the performance with XOR instead of the original hash function and the performance is not so good. Probably the reason is the number of collisions. I did not mentions this, but the array is also used as a key in dictionary that stores some statistics for records with the same values. I use dictionary with EqualityComparer class that calculates hashes and test for equality. By the way how to check for a C# dictionary the number of collisions that appear for a given hash function? Is there some method that can return such info for a dictionary or I should write my own test aside?

Comment: @DanLyons: There's not much you can do other than test and see whether performance is good. That said, standard advice for hash *table* implementers is to make the number of buckets a power of two; then *every* non-even multiplier number is coprime to it.  And standard advice for `GetHashcode` implementers is to use 31 as the magic number; not only is it prime, but multiplying by 31 could be optimized as a shift-and-subtract on architectures where that is faster than multiplication.

Comment: @SebastianWidz: I'm not aware of any documented mechanism for determining the load factor of a hash table. There might be things you can do with the HashSet source code and private reflection, but of course you are playing with fire if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

After discussion in comments of my other answer I did some investigation and found [this interesting 5 years old article form Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/). It says

> [...] In particular, be careful of “xor”. It is very common to combine hash codes together by xoring them, but that is not necessarily a good thing. Suppose you have a data structure that contains strings for shipping address and home address. Even if the hash algorithm on the individual strings is really good, if the two strings are frequently the same then xoring their hashes together is frequently going to produce zero. “xor” can create or exacerbate distribution problems when there is redundancy in data structures. [..]

Therefore XOR seems not to be the best solution for combining hash codes in general. Not sure if that is true in your case because the quality of the hash functions depends on the distribution of the data.

However, if XOR is still to slow, you could try to simplify the hash function. Of course, that will increases the number of collisions, but probably it  performs better than a `GetHashCode` method that is much slower than `Equals`.

You could try something like that for example:

```
public static int GetHashCode(long[] array)
{
    if (array == null) return 0;
    if (array.Length == 0) return -1;
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 31 * hash + array[0].GetHashCode();
        hash = 31 * hash + array[array.Length/2].GetHashCode();
        hash = 31 * hash + array[array.Length-1].GetHashCode();
        hash = 31 * hash + array.Length;
        return hash;
    }
}
```